# Is there a way for geotools PostGIS DataStore to use a JEE DataSource?

Tags: geotools

The geotools `DataStoreFinder` expects a `Map` of properties, including mainly the connectivity information, depending on the store.

For the PostGIS plugin this includes the `dbtype` (which must be `"postgis"`) and the database host, port, schema, database, username and password.

http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/jdbc/postgis.html

In my application, there are other tables which are being accessed using Spring Data (JPA Repositories / Hibernate and Hibernate Spatial).

Is there a way to make the PostGIS connection information to use the standard JEE [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) that is injected by Spring? This way I won't have to duplicate the configuration to the same database and do custom property handling.

Comment: if you can get a JNDI reference for the datastore you could use that to create a new geotools datastore, otherwise I suspect you will need to write new code for the datastores.

Comment: It should be possible to enable JNDI in Spring Boot's embedded Tomcat and add the DataSource to the NamingContext with some JNDI name. Will have a go at it.

Comment: did you  had any luck in integrating datasource provided by spring boot with geotool?

Comment: I didn't use geotools in the end